# Doxygen and preprocesor #include

Tags: c, include, doxygen

I'm trying to use Doxygen, but I can't make it work with my code. In a nutshell, if it contains `#include`'s Doxygen just ignores it. This is a MWE:

```
/*!
  \file
  \brief This foos bars
  \author John doe
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

/*!
  \brief print a net.
  This prints nets.
  \param net Net to print.
*/
void printf_net(int8_t* net){
  printf("%d\n",L);
  for(int i=0;i<L*L*L;i++){
    printf("%d\n",net[i]);
  }
}
```

If I comment the `#include`'s, documentation is generated for the function, but not with them. What should I correct in my code?

Updates:

In response to the comments,

- Using `/**` instead of `/*!` doesn't seem to change the behaivour.
- I have `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES` in my Doxyfile. Basically, I have all the default values of the graphical wizard.
- I'm using Doxygen 1.8.12

UPDATE:

I was enabling `HAVE_DOT` by accident. Disabling that option fixes my problem.

Comment: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdfile

Remove `/*!` and change it to `/**`

Comment: @NulledPointer https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock `/*!` is a valid comment block marker

Comment: Check your config file.

Comment: @Olaf yes it is. But last time it happened for me changing that helped. We could chase config file if /** doesn't help.

Comment: @NulledPointer: If that helped, you had something different wrong and the change triggered some side-effect. `/*!` is (was?) used in QT. With all due respect, but without proof, I strongly doubt this was the actual cause, neither in your code nor the one here.

Comment: @RedPointyJackson What version are you using?

Comment: Do you have `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES` in your Doxyfile?

Comment: @ArturKink The latest, seemingly (1.8.12)

Comment: @RPGillespie Yep. I have all the defaults of Doxywizard.

Comment: I cut the code mentioned and pasted it into aa.cpp, created a default Doxyfile (doxygen -g) and ran doxygen and all the mentioned documentation appeared. Please try the same and check the differences between your input code files and between the Doxyfiles.

Comment: @albert Indeed, it works. I traced it to the HAVE_DOT option. Please, post an answer so I can choose it, if you want. I will update my question with details of what failed. Thank you!

Comment: Strange that this had this effect. Did you have not Graphviz installed but some other program called dot?, still should not have this effect.  When I disable dot and remove Graphviz from the path I get error messages but I still see the documentation. Can you give some more details on the required changes (or post the Doxyfile / its differences from the standard Doxyfile)?

Comment: @albert I would post my Doxyfile, but the only change is the HAVE_DOT thing, I compared both with a diff. Even stranger, I tried now to uninstall the graphviz package and enable HAVE_DOT to replicate my previous situation, and now both doxyfiles compile well! I must have installed some basic library as dependence in the process.